# Consuming a webapi service thats using headers for authorization, in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a restful webservice using WebApi in which I have an endpoint for authentication (`POST account/authenticate?username=&password=`) which returns a token - this token is to be used for all subsequent calls as an Authorization Header (Bearer scheme).

**My Question is this:**

What is the best way to handle this scenario in an MVC application consuming the webservice

**My thoughts:**

For the API calls I've thought of adding the Token to a session variable and then getting the token whenever needed (for request from MVC to WebAPI)

Does MVC support something like this out of the box with FormsTickets or something similar? so we can utilize HttpContext.Current.User - or should I just create a principal from my token and set current.user to that?

Is there a standard way of doing this in MVC?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

**Any articles would be greatly appreciated.**

**Edit:**
It just occured to me, that I should properly write a custom membershipprovider and maybe set a cookie with the auth token - set same expiration time and let authorization handle the rest
How does this sound? to you experts out there

**What I'm during at the moment:**
During login I authenticate through the API and check for the authToken. If its there user is authenticated and I create a FormsTicket cookie with the token as userData, I've set the expiration time of the cookie to the same amount of time as the token.
When the user accesses site after login, I get decrypt the cookie and add the header to my restsharp calls.

Comment: Oauth bearer token should work. And, the idea of session is very bad

Comment: My thoughts exactly...

Comment: My problems is architecting a mediary layer that will hold on to the token without me using a session variable. (unless I push it into a cookie and let the browser give it back to me)

Comment: It depends upon your requirement, you can use the cookie if you are going to use it only in web, else you will have to deal with tokens for each requests. webapi mainly used for more than one platforms.

Comment: well MVC is mostly for web :) - the WebApi service is already deployed  - now i need to consume it in another MVC project

Comment: Do not use session. You would store the token locally in a cookie if you are using mvc, local storage for js. You can look into using Thinktecure to most of the heavy lifting, there is a complete example project for all flows: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/

Comment: Great, so store the token in a cookie - so now I get the token from Request.Cookies["mycookie"]?

Comment: The idea behind this kind of authentication is that it's stateless. The token is stored locally on the client machine and passed over to the API on every request to be validated by the resource server (the api).

Comment: So MVC will act as an intermediary between the browser and the Web service - i see - thank you